# How to get Project dependencies from SBT console

Tags: scala, sbt

Is there a way to inspect the dependencies between my projects in my build (in the sbt console)?

I'd like to check if those configs where successful

```
projectA.dependsOn(projectB)
```

and

```
projectC.aggregate(projectD, projectF)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Mario Camou's answer is valid if you want to see external dependencies. But if you just want to check if dependency configs were successful, you can simply do:

```
> sbt
$ projects
```

This should provide info like: (taken from my Mac)

```
[info] In file:/Users/vaedama/development/projectA/
[info]     projectB
```

which means that your projectA is dependent on projectB

Now if you want to see which project aggregates which project, you can just do:

```
> sbt // enter SBT prompt
$ projects // view all projects
```

The result should look like:

```
[info] In file:/Users/vaedama/development/SimpleProject/
[info]     projectC

$ project projectC // switch to the projectC

$ projectInfo // view aggregations
```

The result should look something like:

```
[info] projectD/*:projectInfo
[info]  ModuleInfo(projectD, projectD,None,None,List(),com.foo.bar,None,None)
[info] projectF/*:projectInfo
[info]  ModuleInfo(projectF, projectF,None,None,List(),com.foo.bar,None,None)
```

which means that your projectC is an aggregate of projectD and projectF

Answer (score 0):

You could try the sbt-dependency-graph plugin from https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph

Answer (score -1):

To get a list of the project dependencies of the current project one can also do

`show projectDependencies`

Comment: Only shows the value of `libraryDependencies`, OP asks for the list of subprojects listed in `.dependsOn`.